# Проблема со SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email

На сайте использую SwiftMailer. Это второй проект, где я работаю с ним. На локальном хосте было всё в порядке.

Но после того как код был залит на хост возникла проблема. Выдает ошибку

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer does not exist' in /home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php:309
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(309): ReflectionClass-&gt;__construct('Swift_Transport...')
#1 /home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(112): Swift_DependencyContainer-&gt;_createNewInstance('transport.buffe...')
#2 /home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(371): Swift_DependencyContainer-&gt;lookup('transport.buffe...')
#3 /home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(348): Swift_DependencyContainer-&gt;_lookupRecursive('transport.buffe...')
#4 /home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/ in <b>/home/nr233103/site.com/www/sport/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php</b> on line <b>309</b><br />
```

Подскажите, что можно сделать